# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint Error

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I want to add role column on users table. But I got this error.

My Users migration

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments("id");
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string("company_name")->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string("phone")->unique();
        $table->boolean("status");
        $table->integer("role")->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('role')->references('id')->on('roles')->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();

    });
```

And my Role migration

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments("id");
        $table->string('name');
});
```

Comment: Try changing `$table->integer("role")->unsigned();` to `$table->BigInteger("role")->unsigned();`

Comment: i hope your `roles` migration has a timestamp before the `users` migration as `roles` has to be created first, the order is important

Comment: I tried bigInteger but ı got same error again. I want to try roles migration migrate firstly but i dont now how do to do it?

Comment: you would have to adjust the timestamp that is prefixed to the filename for the roles migration to be a timestamp before the one prefixed to the create users migration, or adjust the one on the create users migration to be after the one for the roles table

Comment: I change time stamps but ı got error agian

Comment: Please specify your Laravel version.

Comment: @HüseyinDaş make sure to actually rollback and run the migrations again, if you just change the code the changes will not be reflected in the database.

Comment: I use laravel 8 @RianZaman

Comment: And ı use rollback after than migration failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring most probably from wrong migration order. As you are storing `roles` table `id` in your `users` table, you will have to migrate `roles` table first then your `users` table. As I don't know the order of your tables, I will assume from your post's order that the `users` table is being migrated first then the `roles` table, which is why `users` table is not being able to get the id reference of the `roles` table.
Try renaming the date of the `roles` table to a previous date than the `users` table and run `php artisan cache:clear` then `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Just a couple of suggestion, as you have specified you are using Laravel 8, please use the `id();` function instead of using `increments("id");`. To follow Laravel's foreign key rule please use `role_id` as the foreign key instead of `role`.

Instead of using: `$table->foreign('role')->references('id')->on('roles')->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();`

use:

`$table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');`

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```php
$table->integer("role")->unsigned();
```

To

```php
$table->foreignId('role_id');
$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
      ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Make sure that role migrations has pre order in migrations before users migrations,
you can edit the migration name of roles migrations( edit timestamp to make it migrate before the users)

Comment: I changed role migration timestamps before user migration.And change the code as you suggests. But ı got again that error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your code as follows,

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments("id");
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string("company_name")->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string("phone")->unique();
    $table->boolean("status");
    $table->unsignedBigInteger("role");
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('role')->references('id')->on('roles')->cascadeOnUpdate()->cascadeOnDelete();

});
```

Based on the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints), you have used `integer` instead of `unsignedBigInteger`.

Comment: I tried unsignedBigInteger but I got same error again.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, if in your roles table you have the following does it work,
`$table->id();` instead of `$table->increments("id");`?

Comment: I use $table->increments("id"); on roles table.